# How to integrate maximo object in maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have "DMPERSONGROUP" maximo object created from Maximo EAM. 
I have created new resources of oslc type. But its not OSLC type, so how to create its resource in maximo anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

At a high-level you should follow steps similar to this..

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/config_apps/t_add_flds_domains.html

On the maximo side, you can even clone the existing DM resource, but switch it's name and usewith to be used with the OSLC layer.

Comment: I am getting below exception "NotExistOSLCFieldException" when adding an attribute in resource. I checked Maximo EAM backend as well, this attribute exist in Object structure and OSLC Resource. I added it in rdf puller as well. But still getting error. Please advise